# docker-ee-selinux conflicts with 2:container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch

Tags: docker, containers, rhel, selinux

I am trying to install docker on rhel 7.

Step 1
**yum remove docker docker-common docker-selinux docker-engine-selinux docker-engine docker-ce**

Step 2
**yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2**

Step 3
**yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo**

Step 4
**yum install docker-ce**

Error I am getting is:

yum install docker-ce

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 0:18.06.1.ce-3.el7 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2.9 for package: docker-ce-
18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp >= 2.3 for package: docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64

--> Running transaction check

---> Package container-selinux.noarch 2:2.21-1.el7 will be installed

---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.3.1-3.el7 will be installed

--> Processing Conflict: docker-ee-selinux-17.03.2.ee.9-1.el7.noarch conflicts docker-selinux

--> Processing Conflict: docker-ee-selinux-17.03.2.ee.9-1.el7.noarch conflicts docker-engine-selinux

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: docker-ee-selinux conflicts with 2:container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I tried both the suggested options, but it didn't work. I know that I should not be using docker-ce on rhel, but it is just for POC.
Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Please add `yum repolist -v` output to your question.

Comment: I don't think so.
Downloaded and enabled the epel repo and then I tried to eable the server-extras, but it gave me an error.

$ subscription-manager repos –enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms

Error which I got: cannot parse argument: –enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms

Comment: That should be `--enable`, not `–enable`.

Comment: my bad.

It says that rhel-7-server-extras-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.

Comment: Ugh. What kind of subscription do you have?

Comment: it's a sandbox provisioned on-demand. I am not sure about the type of suscription

Comment: It's possible that the channel is filtered, using Satellite or something like that.. If you have a container (as opposed to a VM), then it's unlikely you can run Docker anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fixing conflict error just try

```
yum remove docker-ee-selinux
```

then install your desired package.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove docker-selinux first and then install the desired package,

```
yum remove docker-selinux
```